# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 3 in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying the following commands in Numpy. An error is reported on assigning new sequence to the array slice. The error is expected, however I could not figure out why dimension is reported in error. Why is dimension 3 reported in error, the array is of 1-dimension

```
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(b.ndim) # returns 1
b[2:] = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

>> ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 3
```

Comment: The dimension of a numpy `array` is given by `np.shape(array)`

Comment: The receiving slot, `b[2:]` has space for 3 elements.  You could assign a list of size 3, or a scalar, or an array of the right size.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to broadcast an array of size 5 to an array of size 3 and numpy is trying to help with broadcasting rules. See the [documentation on broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). If you assign with the correct number of values numpy doesn't attempt to do any fancy broadcasting.

`b[2:] = [3, 4, 5]`

Comment: I have just started with Numpy tutorial, haven't reached broadcasting yet. Thanks for the pointer !

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of Numpy. Keep at it, numpy skills are like super powers